# How to change the redirecting url for Google OAuth with supabase?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, supabase

I am trying to set up a website with [supabase](https://supabase.com/) using Google OAuth for authentication.

It's fairly easy and convenient to set up and works really well, by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XM9ziOzWk4) and consulting the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-google).

But unfortunately the Google login page says "***Sign in** to continue to **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.supabase.co***", which looks a little sketchy to users that do not know what supabase is and the random characters make it appear even worse. And there is no apparent indication that this is in fact the website the user is coming from and intended to log in to.

[image]

There are already issues opened on the supabase repo, so it seems to be worked on ([Allow configuration of OAuth2 redirect domain in hosted supabase console #142](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/142) and  [Sign in with Google shows "continue to Supabase.co" #1798](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/1798)).

However, I was wondering if there is a another way to use Google OAuth that could integrate with supabase until there is a proper solution?

*Update*

2 more issues on the supabase github page regarding this problem:

- [Allow custom domains for supabase API #5587](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/5587)
- [Google OAuth -- Change displayed redirect url #2925](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/2925)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting up a Custom Domain on Supabase. It's a paid add-on available to users on Pro or Enterprise tiers.

Custom Domains, Supabase Docs: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/custom-domains

Answer (score 1):

I have not done that with supabase. However, I did it with firebase.

You need to add your domain to google auth. Furthermore, you need to define that callback in supabase auth. I don't know where you do the second part in supabase.

Here is the google guide to do it for firebase https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain

Comment: Thanks, I played around with it but couldn't get it to work yet.